# SQL query: how do I change a value according to a lookup table?

Tags: sql

[update: I am using MySQL 4.1.25 ]

I think this must be a simple thing to do, but I'm a SQL noob and need some help. I have a lookup table that is something like:

### lookup_table

key1, value1
key2, value2
key3, value3
...
keyN, valueN

Then I have another table that has a random list of the keys (with repeats) in one column and I need to add the associated values in the corresponding column.

For example, the second table might be:

### second_table

key3, ?
key1, ?
key1, ?
key40, ?

I need to replace the ?s in `second_table` with the values from `lookup_table` as follows:

### second_table (updated)

key3, value3
key1, value1
key1, value1
key40, value40

This seems like something that a simple SQL query should address. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you state which sql platform you are using as well?

Comment: @Greg: why denormalize in this way. Clue's in the name: rather than redundantly storing the value in second_table, look up the value in lookup_table? This prevents anomalies e.g. what if value1 was changed to something else in lookup_table but not in second_table?

Comment: @onedaywhen: Good point, but this is part of a migration from one system to another. The "key" fields in "second_table" will ultimately be dropped.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I much prefer the following syntax when updating with a join (instead of doing a subquery). It allows you to see results before you update them and know the query's right.

```
select
   st.key,
   lt.value
--update st set value = lt.value
from
   second_table st
   inner join lookup_table lt on
       st.key = lt.key
```

Note that when you're ready to update, select everything from `update` on down.

**Update**: Thanks to tekBlues, I've found out that the above works on SQL Server and Oracle, at the very least.  MySQL has a bit different syntax:

```
update
    second_table st
    inner join lookup_table lt on
        st.key = lt.key
set
    st.value = lt.value
```

Those are the big RDBMS's, so hopefully one of those is helpful.

Comment: This syntax, as far as I know, is not available in all database engines

Comment: @tekBlues: I was under the impression that was ANSI. What DB's isn't this viable in? If that's the case, I want to stop recommending it!

Comment: Anyway, when using SQL Server I prefer it too

Comment: Eric, at least in INFORMIX you can do it, I'm sure of that. It a royal pain, because when you wanna do an update to more that one field you have to use this horrible syntax: UPDATE table SET (a,b) = ((select...

Comment: Sorry. I mean't in INFORMIX you can't use the UPDATE .. FROM

Comment: @Eric & tekBlues: thanks for the advice. I tried the second approach and it worked like a charm. Now I just need to figure out exactly *why* it works. ;-)

Answer (score 11):

Along with the other answers, you could also accomplish this with a join...

```
UPDATE second_table
SET    value = L.value
FROM   second_table S join lookup_table L on S.key = L.key
```

Comment: This works for PostgreSQL

Answer (score 5):

```
update second_table 
set value = 
(select value from lookup_Table
where lookup_table.key = second_table.key)
```

Comment: @tekBlues: Thanks for this. I think it would work if the select statement produced a single unique row, but since it returns multiple rows the set statement throws an error. The join from Eric handles multiple rows though.

Answer (score 0):

In case the lookup table is a query, one option is to use [PostgreSQL WITH clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html).

```
WITH nested_table AS 
(SELECT key, MAX(valA) as valA, MAX(valB) as valB 
 FROM .. 
 ... JOIN/GROUP BY ...
)
UPDATE second_table 
SET valA = nested_table.valA, valB = nested_table.valB 
FROM nested_table 
WHERE nested_table.key = second_table.key;
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution that worked on Postgres quite performantly:

```
update
    second_table
set
    second_table.value = lookup.value
from
    (select
        lt.id,
        lt.value
    from
        second_table st
        inner join (select lt.id, lt.value from ...) lt
        on lt.id = st.id) lookup
where
    lookup.id = second_table.id;
```